# How to fix Geo4Tiff extent in QGIS? GeoTIFF showing up in wrong location

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I have about 100 georeferenced aerial images in GeoTIFF format. They show up in the correct location in ArcMap but when I add them to my QGIS project they all stack on top of each other in the wrong location.

Original = red circle, Newly exported = blue circle

[image: Raster Location discrepancy]

If I export the image in ArcMap to a GeoTIFF or PNG format the newly exported image shows up correctly. The main difference I found is the extent is defined in the newly exported GeoTIFF and there is a .twf file associated to it whereas the original one only had .tif, .tif.aux.xml and .ovr files.

Properties of the two files in QGIS:

[image: Original GeoTiff properties]
[image: Newly exported GeoTiff properties]

Here is the gdal info output for the original:

```
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: PATH_MANUALLY_CHANGED/1DU0000040060.tif
       PATH_MANUALLY_CHANGED/1DU0000040060.tif.ovr
       PATH_MANUALLY_CHANGED/1DU0000040060.tif.aux.xml
Size is 10134, 9872
Origin = (0.000000000000000,9872.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
GCP Projection = 
PROJCRS["NAD83 / UTM zone 15N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 15N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-93,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",26915]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
GCP[  0]: Id=, Info=
          (535.361581921112,7236.6779661011) -> (506871.749064685,5274726.62372602,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=, Info=
          (8399.49717514147,9356.09039547667) -> (510376.9560751,5275602.92547862,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=, Info=
          (6759.20394853962,5102.66824646667) -> (509564.154449496,5273710.62169401,0)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (       0.000,    9872.000) 
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Upper Right (   10134.000,    9872.000) 
Lower Right (   10134.000,       0.000) 
Center      (    5067.000,    4936.000) 
Band 1 Block=10134x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 5067x4936, 2534x2468, 1267x1234, 634x617, 317x309, 159x155
```

I'm hoping to avoid re-exporting all these images. Is there a way to update the extent or QGIS to recognize the extent like ArcMap does?

**EDIT** (See comments):
Here is the gdalinfo output for 1DU0000060040_copy.tif

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: MY_PATH/1DU0000040060_copy.tif

Size is 10134, 9872

Coordinate System is:

PROJCRS["NAD83 / UTM zone 15N",

BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",

DATUM["North American Datum 1983",

ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,

LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],

PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,

ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],

ID["EPSG",4269]],

CONVERSION["UTM zone 15N",

METHOD["Transverse Mercator",

ID["EPSG",9807]],

PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,

ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],

ID["EPSG",8801]],

PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-93,

ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],

ID["EPSG",8802]],

PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,

SCALEUNIT["unity",1],

ID["EPSG",8805]],

PARAMETER["False easting",500000,

LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],

ID["EPSG",8806]],

PARAMETER["False northing",0,

LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],

ID["EPSG",8807]]],

CS[Cartesian,2],

AXIS["(E)",east,

ORDER[1],

LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],

AXIS["(N)",north,

ORDER[2],

LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],

USAGE[

SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],

AREA["North America - between 96°W and 90°W - onshore and offshore. Canada - Manitoba; Nunavut; Ontario. United States (USA) - Arkansas; Illinois; Iowa; Kansas; Louisiana; Michigan; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Nebraska; Oklahoma; Tennessee; Texas; Wisconsin."],

BBOX[25.61,-96,84,-90]],

ID["EPSG",26915]]

Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2

Origin = (0.000000000000000,9872.000000000000000)

Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)

Metadata:

AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:

INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left ( 0.000, 9872.000) ( 97d29'19.50"W, 0d 5'20.54"N)

Lower Left ( 0.0000000, 0.0000000) ( 97d29'19.48"W, 0d 0' 0.01"N)

Upper Right ( 10134.000, 9872.000) ( 97d23'52.63"W, 0d 5'20.58"N)

Lower Right ( 10134.000, 0.000) ( 97d23'52.61"W, 0d 0' 0.01"N)

Center ( 5067.000, 4936.000) ( 97d26'36.05"W, 0d 2'40.28"N)

Band 1 Block=10134x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Add also gdalinfo report about the misbehaving image.

Comment: Updated with gdalinfo report. Thanks!

Comment: The original image is georeferenced with three ground control points and GDAL and QGIS should handle them. You can test GDAL with gdalwarp: `gdalwarp input_with_gcp.tif output_as_north_up.tif`. If QGIS opens the resulting image in correct place then the issue is in QGIS. Perhaps it would like to have more ground control points. But make the gdalwarp test first.

Comment: Are you saying to run gdalwarp in qgis without specifying additional inputs? I ran the tool which used this console call: 
`gdalwarp -r near -of GTiff "MY_PATH/1DU0000040060.tif" MY_PATH/1DU0000040060_copy.tif`
However, the copy image still loads in the same incorrect location.

Comment: Add gdalinfo from MY_PATH/1DU0000040060_copy.tif. There should be no ground control points left in it.

Comment: You can also roughly check the orientation manually. If the GCP is `(535.36,7236.67) ->  (506871.74,5274726.62,0)` it means that the pixel that is 535 pixels to the left and 7236 pixels down from the top left corner should be placed at 506871.74,5274726.62 in EPSG:26915.

Comment: gdalinfo for the _copy GeoTIFF is now added to the end of my question.

Comment: The original has ground control points but also some other georeferencing that appears as `Origin = (0.000000000000000,9872.000000000000000) 
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)`. That is not normal but I do not know how to get rid of it. Show next the contents of the .tif.aux.xml file. You can also try gdalinfo by adding `-- config GDAL_GEOREF_SOURCES INTERNAL`. Does that change the corner coordinates? Document https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#georeferencing explains what that option does.